# XSD to XML (By Hand): How does this convert?

Tags: xml, xsd

So I'm writing an app that parses an XML file that can have a pretty complex structure -- the XSD is massive (it's the XSD for a .trx test results file), and I'm trying develop a set of classes that will handle every possible set of nodes the file can have.

(As an aside, I know I can just generate it from the xsd.exe tool that comes with Visual Studio, but I find the code hard to read and difficult to maintain.  I'm going for something much cleaner and maintainable.)

My question is this: how exactly does this block of XSD convert to an XML node?

The XSD:

```
<xs:complexType name="TestSettingsType">
    <xs:all>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Description" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Deployment">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
                    <xs:extension base="DeploymentItemsType">
                        <xs:attribute default="false" name="deploySatelliteAssemblies" type="xs:boolean" use="optional" />
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:complexContent>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

Where DeploymentItemsType is defined like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="DeploymentItemsType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="DeploymentItem" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:attribute name="filename" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="outputDirectory" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

(I've tried to clean it up somewhat by removing some attributes, as I didn't want this to get too big for a post here.)

I've come up with two options.  Here's the first one:

```
<TestSettings>
    <Description>Some description</Description>
    <Deployment>
        <DeploymentItems deploySatelliteAssemblies="false">
            <DeploymentItem filename="some_file.txt" outputDirectory="some_output.txt" />
            <DeploymentItem filename="some_file2.txt" outputDirectory="some_output2.txt" />
        </DeploymentItems>
    </Deployment>
</TestSettings>
```

Here's the second:

```
<TestSettings>
    <Description>Some description</Description>
    <Deployment deploySatelliteAssemblies="false">
        <DeploymentItem filename="some_file.txt" outputDirectory="some_output.txt" />
        <DeploymentItem filename="some_file2.txt" outputDirectory="some_output2.txt" />
    </Deployment>
</TestSettings>
```

Is one of these two correct, or are both wrong?

I'm strongly suspecting the first solution is the correct one, but I can't seem to generate a .trx file myself to verify it (I've tried everything I know using vstest.console.exe and a .testsettings file, with no luck).  So, I have to generate potential XML by hand.  I'm not as familiar with XSD as I'd like to be, though.

I'm writing an API for this, and I'd like to cover as many as my possible cases as possible -- that is, if it *can* be in a file, I'd like to be able to parse it.

Comment: Well, it can't be the first one because you've not defined `DeploymentItems` anywhere.  Why not validate each against your XSD and see what happens?

Comment: Is the second block of XSD not sufficient to define DeploymentItemsType?  In any case, that's a good plan -- wish I had thought of it. :)  I'll validate against the XSD and report back tomorrow.

Comment: Defining a type is different than defining an element.  You have no element named `DeploymentItems` defined.